# OptionsModel dependency injection in vNext console application

Tags: dependency-injection, console-application, asp.net-core

I have a **vNext console application** where one of my classes takes the `OptionsModel<T>` POCO configuration settings class.

I am unable to get the POCO settings class resolved and injected into my `RabbitMqConnection` class below.

Setting up the `ServiceProvider` is not the issue, it's the resolution of the settings class.

Note, this is a **vNext console application** (not an mvc6 app).

My second question is, and I understand constructor arguments should be kept minimal, but is it not best to pass the two strings as constructor arguments rather than an `IOptions` class as the former method is more descriptive of what the `RabbitMqConnection` class requires? If so, how is this best injected from the class that defined the mappings (`Program.cs` file in example below)

```
public class RabbitMqConnection
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public RabbitMqConnection(IOptions<MessagingSettings> settings)
    {
        HostName = settings.Value.HostName;
        UserName = settings.Value.UserName;
    }
}

public class MessagingSettings
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

appsettings.json

{
    "MessagingSettings":{
        "HostName":"localhost",
        "Username":"guest"
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // tried registration a number of ways as below
    services.Configure<MessagingSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MessagingSettings"));
    services.Configure<MessagingSettings>(Configuration);

    // attempt 1 - get runtime error saying cant resolve IOptions<MessageSettings>
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<RabbitMqConnection, RabbitMqConnection>());

    // attempt 2 - same as above, when i breakpoint on messagingSettings, all the values in the object are null
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<RabbitMqConnection>(factory =>
    {
        // instead of injecting the MessageSettings, pass through the string values (constructor omitted for clarity)
        var messagingSettings = Configuration.Get<MessagingSettings>();
        return new RabbitMqConnection(messagingSettings.HostName, messagingSettings.UserName);
    }));
}

var conn = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RabbitMqConnection>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `services.AddOptions()`